# Testing tool was terminated during test run unable to open the application

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

Facing the above mentioned error only in one machine. If I run the same testcase in other machine it executing fine. Is this issue related technical?

Am using UFT 12.

Comment: had the same twice recently. I guess I made a mistake, as I'm doing a lot of things at the same time on several VMs, but I'm not sure. Problem solved on reboot, but it's still annoying. I'll keep an eye to see if it happens again.

Comment: >>Is this issue related technical?<< well what else could it be? Caused by black magic? :-O